# Removing index from large collection in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I know that creating new index is an intensive operation and, to avoid blocking, it should be run either in background or on secondary members of a replica set first.

What is a recommended way to remove an index from a large collection in MongoDB?

Is it an intensive operation? Will it block the collection or database for a long time? Can I just drop the index on the primary member of a replica set or it is better to remove the index on each secondary member and then step down the primary and remove the index there?

Comment: I know that this is old thread but I found it myself quite high on results list while googling. I've dropped two indexes on collection > 15 000 000 000 documents (so 15 billions/milliards - US/EU), indexes sizing of ~ 200 GB together - it was really fast.
I haven't noticed any fluctuation on application performance graph. What I read somewhere else - mongo just checks if the index is shard key or not.
(correct me please if I'm wrong).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dropping indexes is very fast, I just tested it with a huge index (a million documents text index) and it completed immediately.